# Node Driver MongoDb - handleCallbaak is not defined instead of catch() firing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

Using Node 8.* and MongoDb driver mongodb@2.2.31

I am testing the my code base to see how it behaves if my MongoDB ever crashes. The way I test is to turn the MongoDB daemon off.

The `catch()` statement is not executing. Instead I get the mongodb driver error `ReferenceError: handleCallbaak is not defined` ***when*** `mongo.tempUsers.add(body, token, password)` executes.

Why is this? Shouldn't the `catch()` execute?

```
TempUsers.prototype.add = function(body, token) {
  const user = { "email" : body.email };

  return this.collection.updateOne(user,
    { $set: {
      "token": token,
      "createdAt": new Date(),
      }
    },
    {
      writeConcern: true,
      maxTimeMS: QUERY_TIME,
      upsert: true
    }
  );
```

---

```
const confirmUser = (body, password) => {
  const token = uuidv4();
  const result = mongo.tempUsers.add(body, token, password);
  result.then(() => sendConfirmationEmail(body, token)).catch(e => console.log(e));
};
```

---

**UPDATE**: How my own `collections` object is created:

```
   var collections = {
     tempUsers: false
   };

function connect(dbURI) {
  return MongoClient
    .connect(dbURI)
    .then(function(db) {
      console.log(colors
        .bold('MongoDB default connection open to ' + dbURI));
      initDbListeners(db);
      initCollections(db);
      return db;
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(colors
        .red(err));
    });
}

function initCollections(db) {
  collections.tempUsers = new TempUsers(db);
}


module.exports.collections = collections;
```

---

```
/home/one/github/dolphin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1057
    if(err) return handleCallbaak(callback, err, null);
            ^

ReferenceError: handleCallbaak is not defined
    at Object.c (/home/one/github/dolphin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1057:13)
    at Store.flush (/home/one/github/dolphin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/topology_base.js:68:30)
    at Server.reconnectFailedHandler (/home/one/github/dolphin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:290:18)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/home/one/github/dolphin/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:324:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/home/one/github/dolphin/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:317:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/one/github/dolphin/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:187:49)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:316:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mongodb `node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js` file on your system is different from the [released file](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/v2.2.31/lib/collection.js#L1057).

Remove the `/home/one/github/dolphin/node_modules/mongodb` directory from your project and run `npm install` again.

Comment: This is incorrect. Sorry about the confusion, I am using my own `collections` object for what you see in my own code base... not the same collections object as in the mongodb driver code where the error is.

I updated my original post with how my own collections object is created.

Comment: I don't think it's your collections file, it looks like you have somehow edited one of the mongodb released files. Did you try reinstalling?